# Should I switch to a 13-23T or 12-25T cassette?

Tags: road-bike, cassette

I am currently riding a [Fuji Sportif 1.5](http://www.evanscycles.com/products/fuji/sportif-15-2014-road-bike-ec055667) with original configuration. I am not using clipless pedals currently.

The bike come with 50/34T chainrings and a 9-speed [11-32T cassette](http://www.gear-calculator.com/?GR=DERS&KB=34,50&RZ=11,12,14,16,18,21,24,28,32&UF=2115&TF=85&SL=2&UN=KMH). I noticed that most of the time I am using only 16-24T. Sometimes with 28T for climbing.

As a result, I am considering to switch to a [13-23T](http://www.gear-calculator.com/?GR=DERS&KB=34,50&RZ=13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,23&UF=2115&TF=85&SL=2&UN=KMH) or [12-25T](http://www.gear-calculator.com/?GR=DERS&KB=34,50&RZ=12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,25&UF=2115&TF=85&SL=2&UN=KMH) cassette. However, I am a newbie and do not have experience of switching cassette.

Are my thoughts correct? Moreover, are there other issues that I have missed? For example, compatibility with my bike.

Comment: Should work. Put a new chain on.

Comment: @Blam Thanks, but why should I put a new chain on? Are they related?

Comment: You should always put a new chain on when switching cassettes, if the old one has more than maybe 500 miles on it, since the chain and sprockets wear together and the old chain would not properly fit a new cassette.

Comment: If you occasionally use the 28t, i'd keep the existing cassette. Unless you're racing, you don't need the closer spacing of the 13-23 or 12-25. But a new chain and some derailleur adjustments will make it good to go.

Comment: I did a similar swap to an 8 speed 12-25 from an 11-32 and I was quite happy with the results. Having the gear closer together made it much more likely that I could find a gear with comfortable cadence.  I also have a triple 52-42-30 crankset which helps on the hills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work. Put a new chain on.

New chain as a worn chain will wear the cassette as it is stretched and does not match up.
If the chain is severely worn it may even jump.

Chain is cheaper and should be replaced unless it is almost new.
A cassette will typically last 2-3 chains.

If you sometimes use 28 then why are you giving that up?
Is a closer gearing really worth giving up the range?
Why not like a 12-27T?

Comment: I use an 11-27 with a 50/34. The 50-11 combination is nice for extra speed downhill while the 34-27 proves quite useful on longer uphills. Even though I normally go 34-24 uphill. In a word keep your cassette!

Comment: Thanks all, I would keep the cassette for now then. 12-27 would probably be my next cassette.

Comment: Maybe switch before you totally wear out the old so you have it if you are going to do a mountain ride.